# Why use "#post" instead of "post" in hasPermission check in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am new to spring security. While analyzing the below code change, I could not comprehend why "#post" is used instead of "post" ? Why is the word "post" prefixed with a "#"? post is an object.

```
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#post, 'MANAGER') or hasRole('ROLE_MODERATOR')")
+   @PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#post, 'write') or hasRole('ROLE_MODERATOR')")
    public void updateFullyPost(Post post) throws AppException;
```

I referred to spring security documentation and found the below.

**hasPermission(Object target, Object permission)
Returns true if the user has access to the provided target for the given permission. For example, hasPermission(domainObject, 'read')**

The first argument is supposed to be a target object.

Could someone provide some pointers? Appreciate it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Spring Expression Language](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html) (SpEL):

> Variables can be referenced in the expression using the syntax `#variableName`.

When calling method with annotation like `@PreAuthorize`, the method arguments are passed to SpEL as variables.

If leaving out the `#`, Spring will look for a property in the *root object*, in this case a `SecurityExpressionRoot`. It is where you find the `hasPermission` method.