# spring permission evaluator, sending just id

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

**Custom permission evaluator**

```
    @Component
    public class EventWritePermissionEvaluator implements PermissionEvaluator{

        @Override
        public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication,
                Object targetDomainObject, Object permission) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication,
                Serializable targetId, String targetType, Object permission) {
            return true;
        }

    }



    @PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#event,'write')")
    @RequestMapping(value="/events/{id}/start")
    @ResponseBody
    public Map<String, Object> eventStart(@RequestBody Event event, @PathVariable("id") int id, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws MessagingException
    {
        event.setId(id);
        return eventService.eventStart(event, request, response);
    }
```

In the above example i am sending event object to permission evaluator placing a "#" before it. Why "#"? How do i send just id instead of object?

Comment: Regarding "#", see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31007076/why-use-post-instead-of-post-in-haspermission-check-in-spring-security

Answer (score 0):

For you it would look something like:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#id, 'com.company.product.Event', 'read')")
@RequestMapping(value="/events/{id}")
@ResponseBody
public Event getEvent(@PathVariable("id") int id)
{
    // get Event from dao
}
```

Note the extra parameter for `hasPermission`, that should be the name of your domain model class (can be custom if you implement PermissionEvaluator yourself).